# How can one change the display name of external monitors on a Mac?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, external-display

I am curious about this. I want to rename my monitors Left, Right, and Center.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375808/is-it-possible-to-change-the-screen-display-names-in-macos-for-a-multi-monitor-s